# How do I autofit the containers in my html embed for mobile-responsive view so that it won't overflow and show a scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm using this embed on google site so this make it trickier.
Whenever I resize the embed to look good on mobile view, there ends up being a lot of whitespace on the desktop view and I'm not sure what to do anymore.

TLDR; made some containers for a section on my site and it ended up overflowing on mobile view instead of appearing as a column of containers.

Here's the code: https://codepen.io/Tamanna-the-styleful/pen/MWzXQXb

````
.container {

flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-evenly;
overflow: hidden;

            }```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.